# Swapping two bits in an integer as quickly as possible

Tags: bit-manipulation

I've been looking at some of these books with fun interview problems. One has a question where one is supposed to write code to flip two bits in a 64-bit integer given the indices of the two bits. After playing around with this for a while I came up with the following code, which is faster than the solution given in the textbook, since it doesn't have any branches:

```
uint64_t swapbits(uint64_t n, size_t i, size_t j)
{
  // extract ith and jth bit
  uint64_t bi = ((uint64_t) 0x1 << i) & n;
  uint64_t bj = ((uint64_t) 0x1 << j) & n;

  // clear ith and jth bit in n
  n ^= bi | bj;

  n ^= (bi >> i) << j;
  n ^= (bj >> j) << i;

  return n;
}
```

My question is essentially the following: Is there an even faster way of doing this?

EDIT: Here's the other implementation as reference:

```
uint64_t swapbits(uint64_t x, size_t i, size_t j)
{
  if(((x >> i) & 1) != ((x >> j) & 1)) {
    x ^= (1L << i) | (1L << j);
  }
  return x;
}
```

With compiler optimizations the latter is around 35% slower on a Core i7 4770. As I said in the comments, I'm interested in whether there are any interesting tricks for doing this very efficiently. I've seen some extremely clever bit fiddling tricks that can do something that looks fairly complicated in just a few instructions.

Comment: It obviously fails if the values are larger than 63, but on a low-level function that needs to be optimized, I would put the burden on using it correctly on the user.

Comment: My bad - I just deleted my comment but not quickly enough it seems!

Comment: No problem. It's good to have this clarification. :)

Comment: I'd like to know how you measure speed. I see no compiler or architecture stated. It's plausible that on some machines/compiler combinations your code is slow.

Comment: Note that, strictly speaking, questions about working code belong on http://codereview.com.

Comment: I was testing it on both GCC and LLVM on an Intel Core i7 4770.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question? Can it be done faster on that machine? Do you have a benchmark program to share?

Comment: @PaulR: I'm interested mostly if there's some better trick for solving this in less operations. The code is there just to show what I've come up with, i.e. I'm hoping for an even better algorithm.

Comment: Do you want faster code, or code with fewer operations? Can you show how you compared with other options. Perhaps your benchmark is no good. Often happens.

Comment: I think you can do it in fewer operations - give me a few minutes...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: My benchmark was to first test on a large set of numbers if the speed of the two algorithms were independent of i and j. It was. Then I ran both on a large set of numbers with fixed values for i and j. The other algorithm was slower due to a small number of branch mispredictions, which I expected from having a non-linear program.

Comment: Perhaps your benchmark was incorrect. We cannot tell. We cannot see it. We cannot see the other code. Performance questions are all about detail. It's missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses only 8 operations. Note that this works even when `i == j`.

```
uint64_t swapbits(uint64_t n, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    uint64_t x = ((n >> i) ^ (n >> j)) & 1; // x = 1 bit "toggle" flag
    return n ^ ((x << i) | (x << j));       // apply toggle to bits i and j
}
```

Explanation: x is equal to 1 only if the original bits at indices i and j are different (`10` or `01`), and therefore need to be toggled. Otherwise it's zero and the bits are to remain unchanged (`00` or `11`). We then apply this toggle bit to the original bits (i.e. XOR it with the original bits) to get the required result.

Comment: Using such a toggle bit is a great idea. A funny thing though that with my compiler this is slower than my first attempt, though still faster than the textbook code...

Comment: I'll accept your answer by tomorrow unless someone has an even better idea. :)

Comment: what about an early out if x is zero? e.g: return (((n >> i) ^ (n >> j)) & 1) ? (n ^ ((1 << i) | (1 << j))) : n;

Comment: @samgak: perhaps, but it depends on the architecture (and may also be data-dependent to some extent) - since there are only seven operations introducing a branch could well do more harm than good.

Comment: Great solution: used it in a code-golfing solution in Javascript (basically unchanged) to reduce the size of my code.

Comment: I count 8 operations. See also https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR